# May we have the 2020 "year in moderation" stats published on sites which went live in 2020 too?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, statistics

It seems that most (or all) sites got the annual "Year in Moderation" Meta post published on 19 January by JNat.

However, the Drones & Model Aircraft and Matter Modeling sites haven't received such posts, maybe because these sites haven't been live for a full year yet. They have both been online for ***close*** to one year though, and if no "Year in Moderation" post is published, we'd have no easy way of comparing things when our stats for 2021 are published.

Therefore, I wonder if these stats could be published for new sites as well? Since it has already been done for almost 200 sites, it seems that doing it for just two more sites won't hurt ***too*** much, but will be enormously helpful to those *growing* communities that perhaps might even need it the most!

Comment: I was rather disappointed to see no stats on Drones & Model Aircraft.

Comment: I definitely think it would be helpful on Matter Modeling to have some hard data on community vs moderator moderation tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) to make some changes to [Shog](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9)'s script — it was deliberately excluding the sites as they entered private beta already in 2020 — and just posted these [here](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/106) and [here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/233/3).